What type of power sockets are there on Flixbus in Portugal?
I am spending a few days in Portugal and mostly traveling by Flixbus.
I will need internet but most important power.
In their website they announce power sockets, but not what type.
Does anyone have experience with this?

what type of power sockets do they provide? (USB, regular 220v)
Does every sit have power sockets?
Do the sockets usually work? (my experience in other lines is that this can be very variable)


The ones I remember in Portugal and Spain had the usual European 230V outlets and USB, and the buses were uniform type and new, but others have complained about them not there or not missing, apparently their fleet is not uniform. The Wifi was definitely spotty. I suggest bringing a power bank to be sure.
